# Show that the set of symmetric positive definite matrices with determinant +1 is connected

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

I tried constructing a path $C(t) = tA + (1-t) B$ for any two matrices $A,B$ in the set. Clearly, $C(t)$ is still positive definite and symmetric for $t \in [0,1]$. But I ran into issues in showing $\text{det}C = 1$. Any ideas?

Comment: If I am not wrong, then you are trying to prove that $\mathbb{S}^n_{++}\cap \mathbb{SO}(n)$ from a convex set. Though $\mathbb{S}^n_{++}$ is convex, $\mathbb{SO}(n)$ is not convex. The intersection of a convex and a non-convex set does not create a convex set.

Answer (score 3):

$\det(tA + (1-t) B$ is not going to be $1$ in general.  However, it will be some continuous positive function.  If these are $n \times n$ matrices, so that $\det(cM) = c^n \det(M)$, then you could take
$$C(t) = \dfrac{tA + (1-t) B}{\det(tA + (1-t)B)^{1/n}} $$